# Incorrect displaying FrameLayout item in listview

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, layout

FrameLayout for some reason doesn't work perfectly in listview. I got this incorrect displaying in emulator. In Android Studio items looks nicely. Please help me :)

**In Android Studio**

[image]

**In emulator**

[image]

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGenre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Genre"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Adapter code**

```
public class MyFilmListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Film> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Film> films;


    public MyFilmListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Film> films) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_film, films);
        this.context = context;
        this.films = films;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Film f = films.get(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_film, null, false);

        TextView name = v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        TextView genre = v.findViewById(R.id.txtGenre);
        TextView id = v.findViewById(R.id.txtId);

        name.setText(f.getName() + "");
        genre.setText(f.getGenre() + "");
        id.setText(f.getId() + "");
        
        return v;
    }
}
```

I tried to use LinerLayout and it has correct displaying, however I need FrameLayout.

Comment: Make sure parent layout(listview) has layout_width = MATCH_PARENT & itemHeight doesn't set listItemPreferredHeight/listItemPreferredHeightSmall.

Answer (score 0):

**According to the official documentation**

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organise child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

So you can use **LinearLayout** inside it.
and nowadays better is you should use Recyclerview with ConstraintLayout

Comment: okay, I replaced FrameLayout to a ConstraintLayout, but I got exactly the same result...

Comment: can you share the adapter code?

Comment: yeah, added to a question

Comment: @Kiparisov I check your code and clear output I think your problem in the XML layout where you use ListView there shows another layout. check your transparency and elevation